# How should user agents handle the HTML5 required attribute?

Tags: html, required

This is probably a bit of a noob question, so apologies in advance but...Does the HTML5 specification define how user agents should respond to the HTML5 required attribute (or is it up to them)? In other words, are there any *concrete* rules that define how user agents should behave (e.g. "users should be alerted to the presence of a required field"; "when the user submits the form, required controls should be validated and error messages displayed in the event that they do not possess a value"; etc.)

The HTML5 spec seems to provide some vague guidelines but nothing concrete.

Comment: It's an interesting question, but I really think best explanation is the HTML5 specifications itself. Possibly it will be more fleshed out later when it's put more into general practice.

Although, I will be interested if someone would prove me wrong and supply some elaborating document.

Answer (score 5):

The spec states that when a [`required` element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute) has a value that is the empty string:

> the element is suffering from being missing

If we then look at the [section on "constraints"](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/association-of-controls-and-forms.html#suffering-from-being-missing) (which explains what "missing" means), it tells us:

> An element can have a custom validity error message defined.
>   Initially, an element must have its custom validity error message set
>   to the empty string. When its value is not the empty string, the
>   element is suffering from a custom error. It can be set using the
>   `setCustomValidity()` method. **The user agent should use the custom
>   validity error message when alerting the user to the problem with the
>   control**.

It makes sense to leave the exact implementation of how to display this message up to the browsers, so they can fit it in to their current styles and user experience.

There are examples (screenshots) of how browsers handle this differently [here](http://wufoo.com/html5/attributes/09-required.html), along with browser compatibility information:

[image]

Comment: Thanks! What I find strange is that the spec says that "An element *can* have a custom validity error message" rather than "An element *must* have a custom validity error message"...as this makes it sound as though there is no requirement for a user agent to respond in any way. Is this really the case?

Comment: @user1138681 - I think the browser provides a default validity error message (like those shown in the screenshot) if you don't provide a custom message. There is no requirement to have a *custom* error message.